# How to write this system in the form Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the following system of N equations with N unknowns, with $\lambda$ known and the $a_{ij}$'s also known entries of an m*n matrix A. How would you express the system in the form A **x**=b?
**x** is of course the vector of size n whose entries are the unknowns ($x_i$'s).

Here is the system:

$$\sum _{ i=1 }^{ m }{ { a }_{ i1 }(\sum _{ j=1 }^{ n }{ { a }_{ ij }x_{ j }-{ b }_{ i })+\lambda { x }_{ 1 } }  } =\quad 0$$

$$...$$
$$...$$

$$\sum _{ i=1 }^{ m }{ { a }_{ in }(\sum _{ j=1 }^{ n }{ { a }_{ ij }x_{ j }-{ b }_{ i })+\lambda { x }_{ n } }  } =\quad 0$$

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplifying things one piece at a time.

Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j = (Ax)_i$ (the $i$-th component of $Ax$).

Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ik}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j - b_i\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ik}((Ax)_i-b_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ik}(Ax-b)_i = (A^T(Ax-b))_k$

Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ik}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j - b_i\right) - \lambda x_k = (A^T(Ax-b))_k - \lambda x_k = 0$ for all $k$

Put this in vector form to get $A^T(Ax-b) - \lambda x = 0$.

EDIT: Getting this in the form $\tilde{A}x = \tilde{b}$ just requires a bit of algebra:

$A^T(Ax-b) - \lambda x = 0$

$A^TAx - A^Tb - \lambda x = 0$

$A^TAx - \lambda I x = A^Tb$

$(A^TA+\lambda I)x = A^Tb$

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. One further question though, could that result be further factorized to reach a complete form Ax=b? or that is the most factored it can go?